# How can i use two internet interfaces on osx on mac book pro

Tags: mac-osx, exchange-2007, outlook, local-area-network

I have macbook and for normal internet i have wifi.

Now i have USB etherent which basically uses LAN from company network.

Now i have configured Outlook on mac to link to company so that i can receive emails by turning wifi off and using compnay `LAN`.

Now everytime i use wifi my emails don't work . because i cna only check emails if use company LAN.

I have to Turn off wifi and then check emails  as at that time mac uses LAN.

Is there any way i can both use connections so that i don't need to turn them off

Comment: You should talk with your company IT department.

Answer (score 1):

d00d...

Control Panel -> Network Preference Panes -> ⚙ -> Set Service Order

[image]

Drag and rearrange your interfaces. Try with Wi-fi *above* the USB Ethernet. And then try the opposite. See which works best for you.

Comment: Thanks i did that , But then my internet stops working as i am not allowed to surf internet on USB LAN adapter. I thought internet should get through other adapter but  that wasn't the case. If i have wifi above then email dont work . if i have USB above then internet don't work